# lib's for all browser webkit support

Tags: javascript, css

What is a library I can use for CSS webkit support across multiple browsers including older ones like ie6? Something possibly written in Javascript.

Comment: WebKit is a specific browser engine used by Safari and Chrome, among others. It is not used by any version of MSIE. (If it were, life would be much easier!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're a bit misguided about what to ask for here.  webkit is a specific browser engine.  The only way to have webkit support is for a browser to use webkit (Safari and Chrome).  You won't find webkit in Firefox or IE.

Perhaps what you mean to ask about is specific features that you find in a webkit browser and you want a library that would help give you support for those specific features in non-webkit browsers.  Since there are thousands of potential features that this could be about, to get any sort of meaningful answer, you will have to ask for a library that offers support for the specific features X, Y and Z in non-webkit browsers.

The key part of the question will be to describe what specific features you're looking for and perhaps to classify which non-webkit browsers and browser versions you want the library to cover.  For example, do you have to go all the way back to IE6 or only back to IE8?  Back to Firefox 3 or only back to Firefox 3.5 or Firefox 4?